# How I can make a pdf file of survey results in ResearchKit?

Tags: swift, researchkit

I am doing this code and stuck to make the pdf with survey result. Can anyone help to make an pdf file of result of survey task. Thanks in advance.

```
 func taskViewController(taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController,
    didFinishWithReason reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason,
    error: NSError?) {
        let taskResult = taskViewController.result
        if reason  == ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason.Completed
        {

           // var data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(taskViewController.result)
            //here how can i get the text of steps and results?
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: kSurveyCompleted)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
        if reason  == ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason.Discarded
        {

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: kSurveyCompleted)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
```

}

Comment: I want to make an pdf file from the survey and answers. Can it possible ? if it is, then How to make this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pdf library like this:
https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF
It's easy to create a table inside the PDF and fill it with field/value row.
If you use iOS 11, there is PDFKit "inside".